# Join strings with "and" depending on single or plural result

Tags: python, django, list

What is the best way to compile a string (e.g. for an error message) including a database-dependent result of elements with a connection word like "and" if necessary?

Let's say i have a db result like [Object1, Object2]. I want my message to read "... *Object1.name* **and** *Object2.name* ...".
If there is only a single result [Object1] it should be "... *Object1.name* ...".

I know how to do this in templates, but how do I do this **in code** most efficiently?
If possible I would love to pass on a whole lot of *if:* and *else:*.

Any help is appreciated.

Have a nice day.

Comment: what do you mean with the "if possible..." ? check my answer, it's for the first part of your question, but I can update it as soon as I understand what you mean for the second one :)

Comment: You got it right away. Thanks for your fast answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_of_objects = [Obj1, Obj2, ... ObjN]
" and ".join([obj.name for obj in list_of_objects])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
' and '.join(x.name for x in result)
```